# Mesos/src/examples/python/test_framework.py line 25, mesos.native could not found

Tags: python, mesos

I deploy apache mesos-0.23 on Ubuntu14.04 
This error comes from the last step

```
# Run Python framework (Exits after successfully running some tasks.).

$ ./src/examples/python/test-framework 127.0.0.1:5050
source code:
----
25 import mesos.native
-----
Mesos/src/examples/python/test_framework.py  line 25, mesos.native could not found
```

Anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have mesos python eggs installed?

Comment: @rukletsov I try to build it in a fresh machine, seems the eggs not installed to correct path.

Comment: You can install Mesos eggs separately, e.g. via easy_install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try install mesos through yum or apt-get

https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/datacenter/install/

Ubuntu:

```
# Setup
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E56151BF
DISTRO=$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
CODENAME=$(lsb_release -cs)

# Add the repository
echo "deb http://repos.mesosphere.com/${DISTRO} ${CODENAME} main" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install mesos
```

CentOS 6:

```
# Add the repository
sudo rpm -Uvh http://repos.mesosphere.com/el/6/noarch/RPMS/mesosphere-el-repo-6-2.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install mesos
```

I could import mesos success on it.